# How to load an address that was allocated in a separate function using IRBuilder - LLVM 6.0

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Working on a research project that requires to add load instructions to an analyzed LLVM IR code to load in a function `func_A` addresses that were allocated in a separate function `func_B` using `IRBuilder`. An example is shown as follows.

```
define void @func_B() {
  %1 = alloca [1 x i32], align 4
}

define void @func_A() {
  // load the address allocated above here using IRBuilder in an analysis pass 
  // to the IR code, something like the following:
  // IRBuilder<> builder(); 
  // builder.CreateLoad(val);
}
```

I've been able to find the to-be-loaded `llvm:value*`, i.e., `val` in the above example, but the problem is `val` is a local identifier declared in `func_B` and may conflict with `func_A`'s identifiers (say `func_A` declares a local identifier named `%1` too) when loaded in `func_A`.

How can I load `func_B`'s `%1` without conflicts in `func_A`? Note that I can't pass `%1` to `func_A` as a function parameter since I don't want to change anything of the IR code but adding some load instructions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, obviously, can't do that. It is as if you wanted to access `int a` from the `bar()` in the following example:

```
int foo()
{
  int a = 5;
}

int bar()
{
  ...
}
```

Since `%1` is allocated on the stack, its memory get freed when the function `func_B` finishes, so it may not even exist during `func_A` execution.

The only thing you can do is to store the value of `%1` into a global variable in `func_B` and load it in `func_A`:

```
@var = [1 x i32] zeroinitializer

define void @func_B() {
  %1 = alloca [1 x i32], align 4
  store %1, @var
}

define void @func_A() {
  // load the address allocated above here using IRBuilder in an analysis pass 
  // to the IR code, something like the following:
  // IRBuilder<> builder(); 
  // builder.CreateLoad(val);
  %1 = load @var
}
```